# How to apply the sub-function to a dataframe?

Tags: string, r, lapply

I have a dataframe with a list of strings in it

```
  df$a
=========
"4343-2"
"7889-5"
"4-3456"
"334-45"
"8765-4"
```

I'd like to perform a string operation on the list to remove the dash sign, so I did this..

```
df$a <- lapply(df$a, sub, "-","", df$a)
```

..which only produces a set of completely empty strings. What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can just use `sub` directly.

```
df$a <- sub('-', '', df$a)
```

Instead of the convoluted `lapply` you're doing since sub is "vectorized". You can also use `gsub` if you think there may be more than one dash per entry.